# Which runner for testing with hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

From my professor I'm getting a test file which looks similar to this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SomeObjectTest {

    @Test
    public void testIstPalindrom() {
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

        assertThat("MSG 1", obj.someFunction(" "), is(equalTo(true)));
        assertThat("MSG 2", obj.someFunction("A"), is(equalTo(true)));
        assertThat("MSG 2", obj.someFunction("B"), is(equalTo(false)));
    }
}
```

Since I never used `hamcrest` I'm a bit confused right now. Normally I would only use a single `assert` call per `Test`. I compile and run this test with following command:

```
javac -cp ".;hamcrest-all-1.3.jar;junit-jupiter-api-5.1.0.jar" SomeObjectTest.java
java  -cp ".;hamcrest-all-1.3.jar;junit-jupiter-api-5.1.0.jar;junit-4.12.jar;" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore SomeObjectTest
```

When I run this test it fails also if only one `assert` call fails. Is this due to the fact that they all are in one test or should I use another test runner here?

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I would only use a single assert call per Test

A test method is not designed to perform **always** **only** **one** assertion.
Instead, it has to perform  **as much assertions as required** to valid the acceptance test, that is, the expected method behavior.
It may be **one** but or **more** assertions.
If it makes more sense to make assertion independent as they test a specific case, you should create multiple test methods :

```
@Test
public void someFunction_with_no_character() {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    assertThat("MSG 1", obj.someFunction(" "), is(equalTo(true)));
}

@Test
public void someFunction_with_A_character() {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    assertThat("MSG 2", obj.someFunction("A"), is(equalTo(true)));
}

@Test
public void someFunction_with_B_character() {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    assertThat("MSG 2", obj.someFunction("B"), is(equalTo(false)));
}
```

> When I run this test it fails also if only one assert call fails

As an assertion fails, the test method doesn't go further and pass to the next test method if it exists.
So the actual behavior is normal.
Whatever, you use only JUnit or you mix it with Harmcrest or any testing matcher API, test methods have always be designed in this way.

> Is this due to the fact that they all are in one test or should I use
>   another test runner here?

Actually you use the JUnit Jupiter engine and it is fine.
Indeed, Harmcrest and more generally, testing matcher libraries doesn't use a specific test runner.
These libraries don't execute the tests, they are **helpers** that provide features to make assertions in a more fluent/meaningful way.
Personally, I prefer AssertJ to Harmcrest that is more friendly to use.

Comment: @aetheriaI  don't think. Generally, the idea is having a test method by scenario, not a test method by assertion that makes no sense.

Comment: @Downvoter Please don't downvote correct answers because it doesn't help the OP and other users that visit the post.  If you deem that the answer is objectively bad  and doesn't answer correctly to the question, take care to explain.

Comment: hi, I think the downer may thought the question is about test patterns. e.g: how many assertions in a test? when to use multiple assertions in a test?

Comment: @holi-java the op refers to these matters and I think that I answer to them.

Comment: maybe you are right, but I think the question is talking about how to write tests that op wanted. in this case, it seems to the op should write separated `@Test` for each `assert` and use fixtures to share the common code, since each of them check a specified situation & independently. in other words, the op want to see all of the failed tests rather than just one failed test.

Comment: @holi-java thanks for your feedback. It is interesting. Maybe you are right. But honestly, the test code is rather unclear. So hard to guess if multiple test methods are really required. It may as it may not.

Comment: you are welcome. very detailed answer, hence you have my upvote. however the op want the related `Runner` to fullfill the problem so maybe the `Parameterized` runner in junit4 or dynamic tests in junit5 meet his needs.

Comment: About the runner question it is a possibility. To handle so few cases, I am not sure that it be really needed. Besides, the method dividing handles already the original problem (distinct feedback for methods). However, you could add answer about it :)

Comment: yours is a worked approach now, other approaches the op can get from SO. it is just my opinion, :)

Answer (score 0):

A JUnit test method fails on the first assertion that fails within that method. The assert method throws a `java.lang.AssertionError` which aborts execution of the method. The exception is caught by the test fixture and reported.